# why my searchbar is moving with the spinner?

Tags: html, laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire

I am using laravel 8, Laravel-livewire and tailwind css.
I made this spinner with tailwind animate-spin but when it appears the search bar gets shifted. How to fix this problem?
My code :

```
<div class="relative mt-3 md:mt-0">
    <!--   Search Bar Here   -->
    <input wire:model="search" type="text" class="bg-gray-800 text-sm rounded-full w-64 px-4 pl-8 py-1 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="absolute top-0">
        <svg class="fill-current w-4 text-gray-500 mt-2 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M16.32 14.9l5.39 5.4a1 1 0 01-1.42 1.4l-5.38-5.38a8 8 0 111.41-1.41zM10 16a6 6 0 100-12 6 6 0 000 12z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <!--   Spinner Here   -->
    <div wire:loading>
        <svg class="absolute animate-spin h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-transparent border-2 border-transparent border-opacity-50 top-0 right-0 mr-2 mt-2" style="border-right-color: white; border-top-color: white;" viewBox="0 0 24 24"></svg>
    </div>
    @if(strlen($search) > 2)
        <div class="absolute text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded w-64 mt-4">
            <ul>
                @if ($searchResults->count() > 0)
                    @foreach ($searchResults as $result)
                        <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                            <a href="{{ route('movies.show', $result['id']) }}" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3 flex items-center">
                                @if($result['poster_path'])
                                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92/{{ $result['poster_path'] }}" alt="poster" class="w-8">
                                @else
                                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x75" alt="poster" class="w-8">
                                @endif
                                <span class="ml-4">{{ $result['title'] }}</span>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                @else 
                    <div class="px-3 py-3 text-sm">No Result for {{ $search  }}</div>
                @endif  
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

Here is a video of the problem
https://streamable.com/61l0ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `aboslute` and other positioning CSS rules to the parent `div` rather than the `svg` itself.

```html
<!--   Spinner Here   -->
<div wire:loading class="absolute top-0 right-0 mr-2 mt-2">
  <svg class="animate-spin h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-transparent border-2 border-transparent border-opacity-50" style="border-right-color: white; border-top-color: white;" viewBox="0 0 24 24"></svg>
</div>
```